# jQuery Mobile is rendering layout in strange way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, underscore.js

I am creating an application using Marionette and jQuery Mobile and I have a problem with rendered html code.
To compile the html code I use `_.template(htmlCode, modelVars)` (underscore's method) inside CompositeView's `template` method.

I write that code to get my goal:

```
Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template : function() {
        var tpl = App.Templates.get('my-vehicles-table'); //returns html template
        return _.template(tpl, {});
    },
    itemView : Module.View.MyVehicleRow,
    itemViewContainer: "tbody"
  });
```

Table rows are rendered by JQM when are defined in `tpl` variable:

```
var htmlCode = '<table data-role="table" id="my-vehicles-table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-bar-d">
                    <th data-priority="2">Reg No.</th>
                    <th>VIN</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">Model</th>
                    <th data-priority="1">Type</th>
                    <th data-priority="5">Client</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>DW 12345</td><td>QWER123</td><td>F12</td><td>No Contract</td><td>John Smith</td></tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>';
```

Situatuion is different when `tpl` is only template for the table (doesn't contain rows):

```
 var tpl = '<table data-role="table" id="my-vehicles-table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="ui-bar-d">
                        <th data-priority="2">Reg No.</th>
                        <th>VIN</th>
                        <th data-priority="3">Model</th>
                        <th data-priority="1">Type</th>
                        <th data-priority="5">Client</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
        </table>';
```

And table rows are inserted to `<tbody>` only by CompositeView methods.

Funny is taht if there are some rows declared in `tpl` (inside `<tbody>`) and CompositeView method inserts dynamic other rows, result table has good and bad rendered rows. These are good if were declared in template and those are bad if were added by CompositeView.

What I want? To have all rows rendered by jQuery Mobile (html with special attibutes added to tags when page is rendered).

Thanks!

**--- Edit ---**

The problem is timing of course. You have to be sure you have fetched all data before rendering a view component (VC). If you want to put data from async request to the VC, before you initialize new instance of it check model's/collection's *sync* event.

I.e.:

```
    var collection = new CustomCollection();
    collection.fetch();
    $.when(collection).done(function(collectionRecords){
        collectionRecords.on('sync', function() {
            //collectionRecords has all the data you want to put into the VC
        });
    });
```